# "TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'" with open() function

Tags: python, list, file, max

Ok, this is my code, i want to read from file, then append the number in the file to list, then append some other numbers, and then print the biggest number in the list. here is the code

```
f = open("snake_settings\hs.txt", "r+") #In the file, there is number "7"

scores_list = [f.read()]
scores_list.append(4)    #Random number just to test
print(max(scores_list))  #I want to print the biggest number in a list
```

This is the error

```
File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(max(scores_list))
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post an example of this test file? What is its format? A list of numbers in ascii, one per line?

Answer (score 0):

`f.read()` returns a `str`, which you can't compare to an `int`.  You probably want something more like:

```
scores_list = list(map(int, f.readlines()))
```

Note that this will raise a `ValueError` if anything in the file isn't parsable as an `int`!